# What are the punishments for hugging or shaking hands with the opposite gender?

Tags: sin

Hugging and shaking hands with the opposite gender is prohibited but what are the punishments exactly? Someone said that both the man and woman will have their good deeds erased and they will be thrown in hell. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A man kissed a woman and then came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and told
> him of that, so this Divine Inspiration was revealed to the Prophet
> (ﷺ) 'And offer Prayers perfectly at the two ends of the day, and in
> some hours of the night; (i.e. (five) compulsory prayers). Verily, the
> good deeds remove the evil deeds (small sins) That is a reminder for
> the mindful.' (11.114) The man said, Is this instruction for me only?'
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "It is for all those of my followers who
> encounter a similar situation." https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4687